# Is it possible in Rails to have different assets directories for different environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, gulp

Before executing Asset Precompile (`rake assets:precompile`) I want to apply `gulp` tasks to my JavaScript files which are located here:

```
app/assets/javascripts/my_angular/directives/*.js
app/assets/javascripts/my_angular/controllers/*.js
```

So when I later run `rake assets:precompile` it will pick already processed-by-gulp files.

But the problem for me is that I do not want to simply overwrite existing JS files with its `gulp` output files since I still need original, not touched files for comfortable development.

I think I need to have two folders:

1) development_assets

2) production_assets (auto-generated folder with `gulp` output)

**Is it possible in Rails to have different assets directories for different environments?** (development, production). If yes - how to configure it?

Maybe there is another solution for my problem? Without having two separate directories... I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure the assets path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path) with `config.assets.prefix = '/gulped-assets'`. If you do that in `config/environments/production.rb`, it'll apply to production but not development, letting you still use your original files in dev. You'll need to either make sure your deploy process runs Gulp before asset compilation, or run Gulp locally and include `/gulped-assets` in your repository.

---

You can also [add a preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#making-your-library-or-gem-a-pre-processor) to the asset pipeline, which would leave you needing just one `/assets` directory. You do that by specifying a file extension and a handler, then adding the extension to all the files you want processed that way, just like you have with `.sass`, `.erb`, etc. To crib from the Rails examples, it looks like this:

```
module BangBang
  class Template < ::Tilt::Template
    def prepare
      # Do any initialization here
    end

    # Adds a "!" to original template.
    def evaluate(scope, locals, &block)
      "#{data}!"
    end
  end
end
```

```
# config/initializers/bang.rb
Sprockets.register_engine '.bang', BangBang::Template
```

Then any file containing `.bang` in the extensions will have a `!` appended to it. There's already support for a lot of different tasks out there, so perhaps you can avoid Gulp in favor of a Sprockets-only pipeline. Depending on your Gulp tasks, you might even be able to shell out and run `data` through them to build a hybrid pipeline.

---

Or, you can go the other direction and replace Sprockets with a Gulp-only pipeline. There are a lot of people doing that, and anything I'd write here would be long and only duplicate their work, so check out the [gulp-rails-pipeline](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline) gem and perhaps read [Gulp - a modern approach to asset pipeline for Rails developers](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/03/gulp-modern-approach-to-asset-pipeline-for-rails-developers/) for another angle on it.